# Why can I not apply f_equal to a hypothesis?

Tags: coq

In my list of hypothesis, I have:

```
X : Type
l' : list X
n' : nat
H : S (length l') = S n'
```

My goal is `length l' = n'`.

So I tried `f_equal in H`. But I get the following error:

`Syntax error: [tactic:ltac_use_default] expected after [tactic:tactic] (in [vernac:tactic_command]).`

Am I wrong in thinking I should be able to apply `f_equal` to `H` in order to remove the `S` on both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f_equal` is about congruence of equality. It can be used to prove `f x = f y` from `x = y`. However, it cannot be used to deduce `x = y` from `f x = f y` because that is not true in general, only when `f` is injective.

Here it is a particular case as `S` is a constructor of an inductive type, and constructors are indeed injective. You could for instance use tactics like `inversion H` to obtain the desired equality.

Another solution involving `f_equal` would be to apply a function that removes the `S` like

```
Definition removeS n :=
  match n with
  | S m => m
  | 0 => 0
  end.
```

and then use

```
apply (f_equal removeS) in H.
```

Answer (score 1):

`f_equal` tells you that if `x = y`, then `f x = f y`. In other words, when you *have* `x = y` and *need* `f x = f y`, you can use `f_equal`.

Your situation is the reverse. You *have* `f x = f y` and you *need* `x = y`, so you can't use `f_equal`.

If you think about your conclusion, it is only true when `S` is an injection. You need a different tactic.

Comment: Since `S`is a constructor, the tactic `injection H`will work.